# Sum of digits, sequence (no theory)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem which I tried hard but the solution was very long. 
The problem is as follows:

> How can I find the sum of the digits of a number $$N=1+11+111+1111+\cdots _{2011 \text{ terms}}$$ 
>   My answer was absolutely same as that of Isaac Browne, please see it if you want to know about my attempts.
>   Thanks, everyone.

Comment: The less you can do is to give a name $d_k$ to the $k$-th digit (beginning from the right) and a name $c_k$ for the $k$th **carry** and find  relationships between $d_{k+1},c_{k+1}$ and $d_{k},c_{k}$. I don't know if this is tractable...

Comment: Maybe consider powers if ten, $N=10^0+(10^1+10^0)+(10^2+10^1+10^0)+...+(10^n+10^{n-1}+...10^0)=$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{n=k}\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}(10^i)$$

Comment: Are you looking for just the sum of the digit (sum of digits of $88$ is $16$) or the _iterated_ sum of digits (iterated sum of digits of $88$ is $1+6=7$)? In the latter case, there are clever things involving modular arithmetic you can do.

Comment: I am looking for the sum of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As marshal craft said, we can write this series as a sum of geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{2010}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(10^i)$$
Which we can simplify to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2011}\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{9} = \frac{\frac{10^{2012}-10}{9}-2011}{9}$$
Now a part which may be hard to see is how we go about dividing by nine, so I will go through that as well.
$$\frac{999...90_{2012 \text{ digits}}}{9} = 111...10_{2012 \text{ digits}}$$
Now we must subtract $2011$ from this answer.
$$111...11110_{2012 \text{ digits}} - 2011 = 111...109099_{2012 \text{ digits}}$$
And finally we must divide by nine. As you might be able to see, the last $5$ digits are easily divisble by $9$, so we must divide $2007$ $1$'s by $9$. Going about this process by long division, you can find the following pattern,
$$111111111/9 = 012345679$$
So, the answer to the problem will be this pattern plus the 3 on the end from $09099/9$
$$(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+9)*\frac{2007}{9} + 3 = 8254$$

Comment: Thank you, Isaac. Absolutely correct.

Comment: This is how I attempted my solution also.

Answer (score 3):

One has
$$\eqalign{N&=\sum_{k=1}^{2011}{10^k-1\over 9}=\sum_{j=0}^{222}10^{9j+4}{\sum_{l=1}^9 10^l\over 9}+{\sum_{k=1}^4 10^k -2011\over 9}\cr
&=123456790\sum_{j=0}^{222}10^{9j+4}+1011\ .\cr}$$
It follows that the decimal representation of $N$ consists of $223$ times the sequence $123456790$, followed by $1011$. The sum of the digits therefore is $223\cdot 37+3=8254$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $11\dots1 = (10^n-1)/9$, the sum can be written as

$$\sum_1^{2011} {10^k-1\over 9} = {1\over 9}\left(\sum_1^{2011} 10^k - \sum_1^{2011}1\right) = {1\over 9}\left({10^{2012}-10\over 9} - 2011\right) = {10^{2012}-10-9\cdot 2011\over 81}$$

Now we use the decimal expansion of $1/81 = 0.\overline{012345679}$ to see that $10^{2012}/81 = 123456790\cdots7901234.\overline{567901234}$ (we can see in various ways that this number has $2011$ digits before the period not counting leading zeroes - resulting in $223$ repetition of $123456790$ and then three digits more which must be $123$) and that $(10+9\cdot2011)/81 = 223.\overline{567901234}\cdots$ so the sum becomes $123456790123\cdots678901011$ ($223$ repetitions of $123456790$ followed by $1011$).

Then we just have to add them together, there are $223$ repetitions of $12345679$ which gives $223\times 37=8251$ and then three more ones which gives the sum $8254$.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, all you really need to do is combine the units and find an efficient way to organize it and figure out a pattern

First we can try to solve for much more trivial values of N, say when N has 30 terms. From my calculations $N_{30}=123456790123456790123456790120$

A noticeable pattern is that it goes 1 to 9 then 0 but skips $8$ and then restarts that cycle. I also checked for local sequences of digits for $N$ having more than 100 terms and this pattern still occurs.

Thus, now is just a question of how many times can this cycle within 2011 terms and given 2011 terms, how does it end. Through manual calculation, the actual value of $N$ ends in $...67901234567901011$, thus telling us that the last full cycle ends on the 2007th term, the 0. Knowing that $N$ cycles through the pattern $123456790$, which is 9 terms long, the total number of full cycles of this pattern is $2007/9 = 223$.

The sum of each cycle is $\frac{9*10}{2}-8=37$, found.by using the theorem for calculating sums of arhtimetic progressions and subtracting the missing 8. Thus, up until the 2007th term, the sum of he digits is equal to $37*223$. Then we need to add a further $1,0,1,1$ which are the final uncounted digits of $N$. Hence our final answer is $$8254$$